# Why does FileWriter have a buffer?

Tags: java, buffer, bufferedreader, flush, filewriter

I read that the difference between FileWriter and BufferedWriter is that FileWriter writes directly into a file(char by char), white BufferedReader uses a buffer.
If so, why does FileWriter have a buffer? For example if I make a FileWriter object like this:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("f://test123.txt");
```

and, if I don't flush or close the writer in the end of the program, it would not write anything to a file. That means it alos uses a buffer. Please, explain?

Comment: IIRC, the OS might be doing the buffering, not Java itself.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have a buffer itself but it extends `OutputStreamWriter`, which does, in the form of a `StreamEncoder.`